# Finding congruent equation whilst using modulo arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, euclidean-algorithm

My question is

```
Notice that if r x + s y = t then r x ≡ t mod s . By using Euclid’s algorithm to find integers x and y satisfying
4647 x + 1145 y = 1 , find solutions of the following congruence's.
(a) 1145 a ≡ 1 mod 4647
(b) 4647 b ≡ 1 mod 1145
(c) 1145 c ≡ 127 mod 4647
```

If i can figure out part (a) i believe i can get the rest reasonably easily i'm so close its painful.

so here is where I'm at,

Therefore: 1145a ≡ 1 mod 4647 is

**4647(x) + 1145(y) = 1** *Going by Euclid's method*

Then solved x and y and got:

X = 188 and Y = - 763

**Therefor 4647(188) + 1145(-763) = 1** (which is true)

So now I've solved for X and Y but now i need to work out a to solve the congruence, how do i go about this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: If you don't like the answer $-763$ (I like it fine) add $4647$ to it to bring it in the range $1$ to $4646$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've obtained that $4647(188) + 1145(-763) = 1$ now consider this congruence modulo $4647$. We get that $1145(-763) \equiv 1 mod 4647$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Okay so maybe I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't that make it
 -873635 ≡ 1 (mod 4647) ? because that's where I'm getting lost

Comment: wouldn't that make it what?

Comment: Sorry, prematurely hit that enter button. Oops.

Comment: The point is that your inverse is found via using the Euclidian algorithm, you have already found your $a$ for the equation above.

Comment: If you want it to be positive you can just add $4647$ to $-763$ and  that will also be your inverse since they belong to the same equivalence class mod 4647

Comment: I thank you for your patients, I'm still confused about how to check that I've got the right answer. 

So by adding -763 to 4647, i get 3884, so where do I apply that result to check I'm correct. (sorry im still a bit fresh to Modulo congruence's and its a confusing subject)

Comment: so if $1154(-763) \equiv 1 mod 4647$, then $1154(-763)=4647k+1$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ by definition. You have that $k$ in the equation above ($k=188$), to check it is correct see if $4647(188) + 1145(-763) = 1$, which it does.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you! that was very helpful!